# Php - reading JSON file and dynamically populating a field

Tags: php, html, json

I have this races.json file provided below. I need to create a PHP script that reads this file, and then takes the three nested objects: "races" , "match" , and "stats" and creates a dynamically populated field. Nothing hard coded. When I go to the html web browser there should be three drop down menus that have the data for the three objects listed. That way if I want to modify races.json file, it should automatically update on the html webpage.

If somebody could provide sample code, pseudo code, or even a reference that points me in the right direction that would be super helpful. This is the start of a program I'm working on so I'm trying to get somewhat of my foot in the door to kind of help kick start it.

```
{
"races": {
    "2016_Gobbler_Half": "2016_Gobbler.json", 
    "2016_Ironhorse_Half": "2016_Ironhorse.json"
    },
"match": {
    "M0": "Nothing",
    "M1": "Name",
    "M2": "Gender",
    "M3": "Hometown",
    "M4": "AgeCategory",
    "M5": "Age"
    },
"stats": {
    "S0": "FinishTime",
    "S1": "Pace",
    "S3": "AgePlace",
    "S4": "Place"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_decode` is the standard way of converting JSON to an array.  I'd use the following:

```
<?php

$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("race.json"), true);
var_dump($array);

?>
```

Comment: with true as 2nd param to mkae it asociative array  from json_deocde ;)

Comment: @Louis Loudog Trottier  I update it, I just got what you meant, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there anything I would need to do specifically on the html side with <select> field?

Comment: What do you want to do specifically?  Additionally, if you could mark my answer as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to write a very basic web application in PHP that will create a dynamic search form. The PHP script will take user input from the form and perform basic searches on files local to the webserver. Searches will involve JSON objects stored in those files.

Comment: I simply wrote up an example to give you a strong jump start:  https://hastebin.com/olurekunen.xml  It creates a select tag with the options from the `match` array index.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you so much!